# Table with parent and children inside

Tags: sql-server

i have a table CUST1 with the data inside. each has a unique member_ID as seen in the image.

Now there is another table CUST1_TREE that shows as seen in the image.

i want to show who is the parent of the child. the desired result I want to achieve is **New Table** as seen in the image

I cant embed images yet, so please click the link to see the image. 
any help with the above would be highly appreciated. thanks

[table and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmGFx.jpg)

Comment: $500 up front or show us what you tried so far. ;)

Comment: select
 member_ID,
 member_Name,
 member_D
from CUST1_TREE
where exists
 (select *
 from CUST1_TREE
 where member_Parent_ID not like '0'
 )

Comment: Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34077523/edit) to add this information to your question. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: select
 c1.member_ID,
 c1.member_Name,
 c1.member_D
from
 CUST1_TREE as c1
left outer join 
 (
 select 
 c2.member_ID,
 c2.member_Name,
 c2.member_D
 from CUST1_TREE as c2
  left outer join 
  (
  select 
  c3.member_ID,
  c3.member_Name,
  c3.member_D
  from CUST1_TREE as c3
  ) as c3 on c2.member_ID=c3.member_ID
 )  as c2 on c1.member_ID=c2.member_ID
where c1.member_ID = '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a script that builds 2 temp tables, based on your example, and queries the results as you requested.  Feel free to ask any questions.

EDIT: I Understand your learning and the truth is we are all still learning.  Keep at it!

```
create TABLE #CUST1
(
    MEMBER_ID INT,
    MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(10),
    MEMBER_D VARCHAR(25)
)

CREATE TABLE #CUST1_TREE
(
    MEMBER_ID INT,
    MEMBER_PARENT_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #CUST1
(MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_D)
VALUES
(10,'N1','EMIL'),
(20,'N2','MARIA'),
(30,'N3','AMIR'),
(1005,'N4','VIVI'),
(2006,'N5','RJ'),
(1007,'N6','EMIL J'),
(2095,'N7','EMILY'),
(1055,'N8','TESSAN'),
(10055,'N9','MIKE')

INSERT INTO #CUST1_TREE
(MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_PARENT_ID)
VALUES
(10, NULL),
(20, NULL),
(30, NULL),
(1005, 20),
(2006, 20),
(1007, 10),
(2095, 10),
(1055, 30),
(10055, 1055)

SELECT 
    C1.MEMBER_ID,
    C1.MEMBER_NAME,
    C1.MEMBER_D,
    CT1.MEMBER_ID,
    C2.MEMBER_NAME,
    C2.MEMBER_D,
    CT2.MEMBER_ID,
    C3.MEMBER_NAME,
    C3.MEMBER_D
FROM #CUST1 C1
    LEFT JOIN #CUST1_TREE CT1
        ON C1.MEMBER_ID = CT1.MEMBER_PARENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN #CUST1 C2
        ON CT1.MEMBER_ID = C2.MEMBER_ID
    LEFT JOIN #CUST1_TREE CT2
        ON CT1.MEMBER_ID = CT2.MEMBER_PARENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN #CUST1 C3
        ON CT2.MEMBER_ID = C3.MEMBER_ID
WHERE CT1.MEMBER_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Hope this helps!  If this answers your question, be sure to check this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will definitely check it out when I get back in front of a machine. And I am truly new to this so didn't know how to ask the right way (if I was confusing)

Comment: @BlackLeg_Sanji Understand, no sweat.

Comment: Thanks bro, this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks so much for the help